# Windows cmd in python using os.system() not working with VLC commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, vlc, os.system

I've registered VLC media player as a system variable so when I type vlc into commandline it opens no matter what. I'm trying to write a python program which gives vlc a filename to open in fullscreen but i cant even get python to open vlc using `os.system()` (I know python has a vlc module, I'm learning about how to use `os.system()` though)

this is what I'm currently trying to run

```
import os

cmd = 'vlc'
print (cmd)
os.system(cmd)
```

the python shell opens and prints the 'vlc', and a command window pops up for a moment and disappears.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use `os.system()` when its documentation has said for many years you should use `subprocess` instead?

Comment: Apparently you are on Windows. Perhaps you should [edit] your question to include this information. Running graphical applications is quite different on different platforms.

Comment: new to Python. didnt know about subprocess. will do on the question update.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows.

```
os.system("C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe") #Or mention your vlc.exe path
```

Using subprocess to open vlc player

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe"])   #Or mention your vlc.exe path
```